# .NET classes for Visual Studio projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project

Does Visual Studio expose any classes which can be used for loading a project (`.vcproj` file) and changing some of it's properties?

Our solution currently has around 70 projects, ~60 of which are Visual C++. I'd like to expreriment with some settings (turning on/off optimizations, changing linking settings, etc.). Unfortunately, .vsprops file aren't really suitable for the purpose, as the settings for different projects are are frequently set to some "manual" value (not "inherited") for historic reasons.

Is there some class I can load the project with and tinker with it? Like (off top of my head):

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;

Project project = Project.Load("MyProject.vcproj");
project.Configurations["Debug"].CompilerSettings.OptimizationLevel = OptimizationLevel.Full;
```

Having such class will allow me to quickly sketch C# "scripts" using LINQPad to test various configurations.

Comment: Note: I'm not asking about "finding a tool", I'm asking about (perhaps undocumented) functionality Visual Studio - a primary tool for many developers - provides :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Microsoft's project Roslyn does what you want. I've never used it, but heard a lot of good things about it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx

Among other features, it exposes the object model of a solution / project. Check the "Working with a Workspace" chapter on the docs.